# Override R's assignment of .Last.value

Tags: r

In R, whenever a calculation completes without throwing an error, the result is automatically stored in a variable named `.Last.value`. Being a lazy typer, I'd like to change the name of that variable if possible, for example to `..`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
delayedAssign("..", .Last.value)
```

That will look up the value of `.Last.value` when you use `..`

```
5
# [1] 5
.. + 2
# [1] 7
```

Though it's pretty fragile relying on the value of `.Last.value` so I'm not sure how robust this is.

Comment: Thanks! And I agree using even .Last.value is sketchy for anything but interactive prototyping

Comment: Ah, after playing a bit I think your solution makes it so that the first time you ask for the value of `..` it behaves as expected, but thereafter it retains the value it was assigned the first time it was referenced. So, `1+1;print(..);1+2;print(..)` prints `2` then `2` then `3` then `2`, when my use case (likely incompletely explained in the OQ), would have expected the last print to be `3`. Maybe I'll just make a function `..=function() .Last.value`